# Ubuntu with GUI: does shutting down the system with the GUI have the same effect as shutting down the system using a terminal?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, gui, reboot

When using a desktop environment on Ubuntu, you can shutdown or restart the system using the GUI.

Alternatively, you can shutdown the system by opening a terminal and using either of these commands (older versions of Ubuntu may require `sudo`):

```
user@hostname:~$ shutdown -P now
user@hostname:~$ poweroff
```

Likewise, one can reboot the system using either of these commands (older versions of Ubuntu may require `sudo`):

```
user@hostname:~$ shutdown -r now
user@hostname:~$ reboot
```

So here is the question: is shutting down the system using the GUI and a terminal exactly the same? Or does shutting down using the GUI perform additional steps like making sure that the desktop environment is terminated gracefully before shutting down or rebooting the system?

I specifically want to know about Xubuntu, but it would also be nice to know about Ubuntu with Gnome, Kubuntu and Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have not perused the source of those distros and gnome or kde specifically... however, I would be stunned if they implemented any custom code surrounding core shutdown processing. Shutting down, restarting, and halting are low level tasks, not GUI implementations (like gnome or kde).

The shutdown command you see is implemented by sysvinit (or your init system) that  handles stopping services that it (init system) started before sending a notification to the kernel to take care of the rest. More than likely, all the gnome "poweroff button" does is end up calling that same shutdown.

You might find this interesting:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/how-does-the-system-shutdown-of-a-linux-kernel-work-internally